# Installed PCIe network card - computer won't boot

Tags: pci-express, network-adapter, dell-vostro

I have a new Dell Vostro 460, that has onboard video, and an Dell-added a PCIe video card. It has 1 16x PCIe slot and 4 1x PCIe slots.

When I plug in a PCIe gigabit network card ([link](http://www.amazon.de/InLine-Gigabit-Netzwerkkarte-Express-Slotblech/dp/B003ZVILKC). lspci: 'Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)') in one of the 1x slots, the computer won't boot. At all. No error beeps. The power comes on, and then nothing. If I remove the add-on video card, and put the NIC in its slot, the computer, and network card, works fine.

The card 'seems' to be 1x PCIe, and its socket size also seems to suggest this.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your link died, so I removed it.  Please  update the question with a working link to the product.

Comment: Also, what's the wattage of your power supply?  You may be over-drawing with both add-in cards in at once.

Comment: Fixed link. Power supply supplies 350 watts. You think that this tiny NIC will draw that much power?

Comment: Hmm. The SO changes my link so it doesn't work: http://www.amazon.de/InLine-Gigabit-Netzwerkkarte-Express-Slotblech/dp/B003ZVILKC

Answer (score 2):

With a 350W PSU, a discrete graphics adapter, and the symptoms you're describing, it sounds like you may be over-drawing with both add-in cards in at once.

We generally use 425W as a minimum for any computer with two hard drives or one HDD and a video card, as the 350W's are always too borderline. So as "tiny" as that NIC may be it still might be enough to tip the scales and prevent POST, at least in my opinion.

The first thing I'd do is hook up a 500W PSU and see how it goes.

Comment: Dell's documention says 350W. Just opened up the box to check, and the  PSU is only 300W.... stupid Dell.

Comment: @klokop Yuck. :)  Perhaps a local computer shop would let you test with a bigger power supply if you intend to buy it if it works?

Comment: Oh, but wait. If I take out the video card, and leave the NIC in one of the 1x PCIe slots, the PC still won't start! Surely the PSU should be able to supple power to just the NIC?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my d-link card,   check your BIOS  make sure the onboard network is off,  i did this and now mine working great

Comment: I did, and it was.